# scp does nothing but print usage only even after putting destination

Tags: linux, scp

I'm trying to copy a file on my home network using scp. However, every time I run it, it just prints usage instructions

```
scp -i ubuntu@xyz.in:temp/backups/file.txt .
```

and it only keeps on printing

```
usage: scp [-346BCpqrTv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
        [-J destination] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port]
        [-S program] source ... target
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/655720/edit) to include the output of `type scp` and `alias scp`

Comment: @roaima done can you help

Comment: Printing the usage is `scp`s cry for the _identity_file_ argument for `-i`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `type scp` and `alias scp`

Answer (score 3):

Read what it is telling you:

> scp [-346BCpqrTv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-J destination] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target

The reason might be more obvious I strip out the optional arguments you've not used:

```
scp -i identity_file source target
```

But you only provided 2 arguments after '-i'